# Can't call any Blockly methods in index.html even though it works in other .js files and a workspace is shown

Tags: javascript, html, blockly, google-blockly

I'm trying to create a tool where you can create HTML pages using Blockly blocks. I already have a page that shows my workspace and my self-created block. Now I want to write a script that gets the code from the workspace. Normally there is a `workspaceToCode` method in the Blockly library. Unfortunately I can't access any Blockly methods or really anything Blockly-related in my index.html.

I've looked up similar projects and can't seem to find any differences. I'm loading `blockly_compressed.js`, `blocks_compressed.js` and `javascript_compressed.js`. And because it shows me a workspace with "functioning" blocks I'm pretty sure that the paths are correct.

See below what I tried and thanks in advance for your help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        ...
    </style>

    <script src="node_modules/blockly/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/blockly/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/blockly/msg/en.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/blockly/javascript_compressed.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

...

<script src="html_blocks.js"></script>
<script src="html_generator.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>


<script>
    function update(event) {
        var code = HtmlGenerator.workspaceToCode(workspace);
        document.getElementById('HTMLCodeDiv').innerText = code;
    }
    workspace.addChangeListener(update);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The error it is giving is "unresolved function or method" for the `workspaceToCode` method as well as the `addChangeListener` method.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Where is `HtmlGenerator` defined?

Comment: HtmlGenerator is defined in a separate file called html_generator.js but for what I know it is working fine. The problem is that all the functions that come from the Blockly-package work fine in all the .js-files (main.js, html_generator.js and so on) but cannot be accessed by the index.html.

It is kinda hard to give an example in a comment because of length-restrictions. But you can really call any Blockly method in a simple script-block and it will tell you that the method is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't shown all of your code, I can't provide a precise answer to explain exactly what's gone wrong for you here, but I can say that Blockly in a classical (non-module) script tag adds itself to the `window` as follows:

```js
// ...
  } else { // Browser
    var factoryExports = factory();
    root.Blockly = factoryExports;
  }
// ...
```

where `root` is `window` (by way of `this`) and `factory()` is the entire Blockly code. All Blockly functions are namespaced inside of the `window.Blockly` object, so there is no such `window.workspace` variable that would be created unless one of your other scripts (not shown) created this and attached it to the window.

If you open your browser console, you can type `Blockly.` and see the list of available properties that were imported by the scripts. The other Blockly scripts simply attach more properties to the global `Blockly` object that was created by the first script tag. `Blockly.Workspace` and `Blockly.workspaceToCode` are some of these properties, and you can call `Blockly.inject` to create a workspace.

For example,

```js
const blocklyWorkspace = Blockly.inject("blockly-container", {
  toolbox: document.getElementById("toolbox")
});

document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    const code = Blockly.JavaScript
      .workspaceToCode(blocklyWorkspace);
    console.log(code);
  });
```

```css
#blockly-container {
  height: 100vh;
}
xml {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blockly/8.0.0/blockly.min.js" integrity="sha512-m19pjKFpHlhFqUAWB49IQt7ip1P7UDKyV0k0f7UGnN8pXSLFjtvsrRcDlwRw+ZhaNeqQTwHwE9+CJgPAWUyA9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button>Workspace to code</button>
<div id="blockly-container"></div>

<xml xmlns="https://developers.google.com/blockly/xml" id="toolbox">
  <block type="text_print"></block>
  <block type="text"></block>
</xml>
```

It strikes me as an antipattern to use `node_modules` in script tags like this, even though some of the Blockly examples do this. Usually, you'd use a bundler of some sort (webpack, parcel, vite, browserify, rollup, etc) to allow you to dynamically import the code using modules (example below). Or else keep your build without any local dependencies and use a CDN and take advantage of client caching (as shown above). Using `node_modules` directly seems like the worst of both worlds, especially without a minification build.

For example, you can use [parcel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel) to build your app for the web. A bundler makes it easy to use `node_modules` without specifying the paths. You can develop using modules rather than legacy UMD script tags, which help you organize the project into chunks and avoid polluting the window with shared data.

The example below is contrived for clarity, but hopefully you can extrapolate the approach (or something similar) to your project.

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
  #blockly-container {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  xml {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="blockly-container"></div>

  <xml xmlns="https://developers.google.com/blockly/xml" id="toolbox">
    <block type="text_print"></block>
    <block type="text"></block>
  </xml>

  <xml xmlns="https://developers.google.com/blockly/xml" id="start-blocks">
    <block type="text_print" id="N4+B!H6xh[=wx]z^LqGk" x="38" y="38">
      <value name="TEXT">
        <shadow type="text" id="~uw6Vr9}hxZS-=a(Zjt{">
          <field name="TEXT">hello world</field>
        </shadow>
      </value>
    </block>
  </xml>

  <script src="src/index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import Blockly from "blockly";
import generateCode from "./generate-code";

const blocklyWorkspace = Blockly.inject("blockly-container", {
  toolbox: document.getElementById("toolbox")
});

Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(
  document.getElementById("start-blocks"),
  blocklyWorkspace
);

console.log(generateCode(blocklyWorkspace));
```

`src/generate-code.js`:

```js
import Blockly from "blockly";

export default blocklyWorkspace =>
  Blockly.JavaScript
    .workspaceToCode(blocklyWorkspace);
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/parcel/lib/cli index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "blockly": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Building and running:

```bash
npm i
npm start
```

Now, navigate to (by default) http://localhost:1234 (or whatever `parcel` tells you on the console) and begin developing.

Comment: I really appreciate all the hard work you put in. It helped solve the problem. Unfortunately I can't really tell what it was in the end but reimporting blockly and choosing a different way than the node_modules one did it for me in the end! (IMO it really is just a different path)

Thank you a lot for answering badly worded day-old questions on stackoverflow. People like you are what the world needs more of <3

Comment: No problem. I forgot to mention, but it might also matter what version of Blockly you're using. I don't know the library super well but older versions may add more than the `window.Blockly`. Unlikely.